# How to chop the first few characters from the UITextField text in Swift3?

Tags: string, swift3, xcode8

I have a UITextField which shows the value as "+965 98765432". Now i want to trim the first five characters "+965 " and get the value as 98765432 only.
I know about :

```
ar myString = "Hello, World"
myString.remove(at: myString.startIndex)

myString // "ello, World"
```

But how to remove the first 5 characters from the UITextfield text as i have asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Swift 3 you can do it with

```
let string = "+965 98765432"
let number = string.substring(from: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
```

However, when you go to Swift 4 this method will be marked as deprecated so you can use:

```
let string = "+965 98765432"
let number = String(string[string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy:5)...])
```

Comment: This would crash the app if the String doesn't contain enough characters

Answer (score 2):

Please check :

```
let string = "+965 98765432"
```

**Swift 3**

```
let finalStr = String(string.characters.dropFirst(5))
```

**Swift 4**

```
let finalStr = String(string.dropFirst(5))
```

Comment: Nice. And in Swift 4 this becomes `let finalStr = String(string.dropFirst(5))`